# Power Pivot model disappears

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a fairly simple (two tables, < 1,000 records and < 60 columns) PowerPivot data model in Excel 2016. It has happened twice now that while I am editing my pivots from the data model, the data model completely disappears from the file. I have to rebuild it from scratch. Error message below. I re-installed PowerPivot after the first time, but error came back.

---

"Sorry, PowerPivot can't open the Data Model because there was a COM exception while opening. You might be opening a workbook on a corrupt installation of Excel. Click Details for more information."

============================

## Error Message:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

============================

## Call Stack:

at Microsoft.Office.PowerPivot.ExcelAddIn.InProcServer.LoadSandboxAfterConnection(String errorCache)
   at Microsoft.Office.PowerPivot.ExcelAddIn.InProcServer.LoadSafeSandboxAfterConnection(String errorCache)
   at Microsoft.Office.PowerPivot.ExcelAddIn.InProcServer.LoadOLEDBConnection(Boolean raiseCompleteEvent, String errorCache)

============================

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: And here is the question: what is causing this error?